# Can't do a mysqldump from a PHP Script (Big data)

Tags: php, mysql, database, dump

I'm trying to make a database dump from my php script, when I only try to dump the database structure it works just fine, but when I try to dump the data the application crashes, I tried using the options : --opt and --quick, but that didn't work for me.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you call `mysqldump` from commandline and get a complete dump?

Comment: "the application crashes" - more info please. error message + check the web server error log + provide (minimal) application code.

Comment: Yes, I use the same code to dump my database structure, but when I try to dump the data it crashes, I guess it has to do with resources or memory. Maybe it needs to load data in memory before writing the dump file.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the error message is "Web page inaccessible" I'll check the log file.

Comment: It's a memory error : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted. The problem is that I don't want to change the default value 128M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this before your script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

You may also need this line to make sure PHP doesn't time out:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Well what do you expect? You're running a database dump in PHP, this is a big operation, I'm giving you the code that will allow it to finish.

Comment: I'm not telling it's not working with the code you gave, I knew that already, I was just wondering if there was a better solution then setting the time limit to "unlimited" !

Comment: Then you should have put that in your question, you're not being very respectful of the community here (in this question and others), we don't get paid for this and we shouldn't have to try and read your mind. And the answer is no, you would have to export tables individually.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean being rude. well then there's no other way I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to increase the execution time of your application. From the code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

Alternatively, you can edit the `max_execution_time` field in your php.ini file.

Comment: I've already done that, it's a memory limit problem, and I guess the only solution left is to set a bigger value than the default one (128M)